# Trouble locating YouTube video link on YouTube search results page with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea

I am trying to locate a link of YouTube video with the Selenium Firefox webdriver. Right now, I am getting a NoSuchElementException. It visits the YouTube page correctly but cannot locate that element that is the first link. My goal is to be able to copy the url to the first video into a String.

```
    String ytlink = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + searchTerm;
    driver.get(ytlink);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    By cssSelector = By.cssSelector("#item-section-209606 > li:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > h3:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(1)");
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(cssSelector);
```

I am using Intellij and have the lastest version of selenium. Firefox is used to locate the CSS Selector by using Inspect Element - copy CSS Selector.

[image: HTML from YouTube Search Results page]

I am wanting to retrieve the a href="/watch?v=WPvGqX-TXP0" and store that into a String

Comment: Can you consider to sum up your exact manual steps for the actions you are trying to perform? Thanks

Comment: Once I get to the YouTube search results page, I am trying to retrieve the link of the first video and store it in a String. However, all youtube videos are set up with https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9YlEpv-FrWU so the only information I need from the page is that unique code after the v=. The entire  string for "watch?v=9YlEpv-FrWU" is stored in the HTML of the search results page. I will add a picture to my original post.

Comment: As smit9234 mentioned below, the item-section number changes each search which is where my error appears. If singling out the first video is not ideal, perhaps store the search result elements in an ArrayList and then access the first one?

Comment: Use selenium get attributes function

Answer (score 0):

Does your search result always return the same #item-section-?  If this is an auto generated number than it could cause the NoSuchElementException.

I was able to use the following css selector to click on the first link that is returned for the YouTube search:

```
div > div > div.yt-lockup-content > h3 > a
```

Comment: The css selector you mentioned is not unique. In my case it returned 20 matches. Thanks